# Where are Minecraft iOS saves stored?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I really need to find my Minecraft saves folder on my iPod. I'm trying to convert my creative file into a survival file, which I now know how to do, but one of the steps is to go into the Minecraft saves folder. So where can I find the folder?

Comment: I didn't know you could play Minecraft on an iPod.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Extremikks. If you check out our [FAQ], you'll see that we do indeed have different standards than a typical forum when it comes to asking questions. This is in order to make it easier for people to answer what you've come to ask. Giving us detailed and thorough information as to the nature of your problem will be the best way for us to help you and understand what it is you're looking for. While we appreciate your feedback, our current rules and standards have served us well for the past 3~ years, and we hope you understand that they're there for a reason. :)

Comment: @SimonL Minecraft has an iOS version. Now, I don't own any Apple products, but if I'm not mistaken, the iPod Touch and the iPhone both make use of the iOS (as well as the iPad and the 2nd generation Apple TV).

Answer (score 9):

The Minecraft PE saves are stored in the Minecraft application folder which is located at `Apps/com.mojang.minecraftpe/Documents/games/com.mojang/minecraftWorlds/<WorldName>`.

You will need a program like iExplorer in order to access the filesystem of the device.

Comment: @Extremikks12345 If you find this answer helpful, you can accept it by clicking the "checkmark" that appears on the left hand side.  There are plenty of folks in the Arqade community that want to help out, but I understand the rules do take some getting used to.  It looks like kalina's provided the answer you are looking for, so hopefully that helps.  If you do have any questions about the site policies, you can ask them on [Meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/).